# "What's going on?" vs. "What's happening?"

Tags: word-choice, colloquialisms

Is there a semantic difference between *What's going on?* and *What's happening?* Can they be used interchangeably?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, they can. But consider this difference:

"What's going on?" can also be accusatory, as in "What's going on here? I didn't give permission for you to have a party in my house!"

"What's happening?" ranges from innocuous to friendly. It's a "defanged" version of "What's going on?" But most of the time, the latter statement is innocuous as well.

Comment: Other tones are possible as well: surprised, suspicious, shocked, bewildered. But I can't see any difference of usage between the two sentences for the tones I listed.

Comment: I’d suggest: for any given tone, they have the same usage.  But their relative frequencies in different tones will vary, slightly: accusatory “what’s going on?” more common than accusatory “what’s happening”, inquisitive “what’s happening?” slightly more common than inquisitive “what’s going on?”…

Answer (score -1):

It's the same with a little difference on each.

What's going on? something "running" that continues to happening right now

What's happening? as Event and occurrence.

Comment: What makes you think "What's happening" is not asking about something that continues to happen right now? Do you need to use "happening" after "to"?